# Разработка клиент-серверного приложения на Android

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio

**UPD**: вопрос решён. Учить Java и студию, а пока буду использовать **Cordova**-у

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые гики.
Я сейчас задам вопрос, который задают обычно школьники. Но начну с вступления, дабы лучше объяснить в чём моя задача, и что я уже сделал.

Я являюсь WEB-программистом уровня самоучки. У меня есть собственная онлайн игра. Браузрека. Поэтому и пишу севрерную часть на PHP, а клиентскую на JS; вёрстка HTML + CSS; как бд использую MySQL. Сервер работает на Debian-е. Связка Nginx + Apache. Всё это управляется панелью ISPmanager. Браузерные игры хороши свой кроссплатформенностью. Не важно какая платформа, главное иметь под рукой браузер. Но всё же есть и несколько недостатков в таком подходе. Один из них, так это большой объём скачиваемых данных при использовании мобильного интернета. Это влияет на время открытия страницы. А если трафик лимитирован или тарифицирован, то дела обстоят куда хуже. Да и вообще, даже при быстром и безлимитном интернете многие используют смартфоны, и предпочитают играть через приложения разработчиков. Не говоря уже о том, что наличие приложения в маркете увеличит кол-во игроков.

Вот тут я и задумался над написанием своего собственного приложения под Android, для игры из него. Решил писать не игру с нуля, а по сути мобильный клиент, который в себе будет содержать нужные ресурсы для игры (изображения, текст, звуки, разметка) и только подгружать из сети данные из БД, результаты серверных вычислений и т.д.

Окрылённый своей идеей я побежал устанавливать последнюю Android Studio. Устанавливаю, настраиваю, качаю SDK и прочие нужности (благо в этом разобрался давно, когда шил свой смарт). Создаю проект с готовым активити (Blank Activity), учусь писать, использую уроки с сайтов. О, да я крутой программер на Java, подумал было я. Но не тут-то было. Мне нужно написать приложение по типу приложения ВК. Сегодня провозился весь день разбираясь в стандартном активити Navigation Drawer Activity. И понял я, что мне учиться писать на Android ещё месяцы. А я замахнулся на клиент-сервер. Много почитал, почитал первую главу "Философия Java" Брюса Эккеля. Посмотрел содержания. И почти ничего не нашёл про клиент-сервер. Или я плохо искал. Но вот если с Java я ещё имею возможность подружится (более-менее понятно), но с XML, а тем более со связкой Java + XML, я никак не могу найти общий язык! :(

Итак, собственно нубский **вопрос**: что вы посоветуете мне делать, имея только знания PHP и HTML (и всего прилагаемого к ним). Можно ли как-то выкрутится из моей ситуации. Знаю, что можно писать на C# под Unity, но я не подружился со средой Unity. Или мне придётся смириться, и пару месяцев просидеть за изучениям Java + XML?

Прошу прощения за огромное кол-во текста.

Заранее благодарю за понимание и помощь. С уважением, Юрий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кроме как потратить месяцы, а возможно и годы и изучить программирование вам нечего посоветовать. 
Искать у Эккеля что-либо про клиент-сервер нет никакого смысла, ибо он все-таки дает знания по языку, а не по решению конкретной задачи.
К стати не понятно, раз вы знаете PHP почему есть проблемы с XML. Парсеры по своей идеологии (да и по методам почти тоже) и там и там примерно одинаковые.
На C# писать нужно не на Unity, a на Xamarin, что однако не отменяет необходимость изучения Android API.

Comment: С XML я никогда не работал вообще. В PHP использую шаблонизатор Smarty и всю разметку делаю на HTML. Вообще никогда не сталкивался с XML. Ладно. Буду учить Java.

Хотя мне вот предложили как вариант "PhoneGap", "Apache Cordova" и "NativeScript". Что можете на этот счёт сказать?

Comment: @intro94 как человеку работающему с вебом, PhoneGap в самый раз

Comment: @AdamLuisSean спасибо. Вот только разобраться осталось. Сейчас почитал: что PhoneGap, что Кордова - консольные и фиг разберёшься. Я-то думал это будут небольшие студии. :)

Comment: @intro94 есть [плагин](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7436?pr=phpStorm) для IntelliJ Idea

Comment: @AdamLuisSean я этот плагин ставил сразу. Но не разбирался как он работает. Но кажется, понял, как работать ручками. Просто пишешь обычную страницу / сайт на HTML + JS + AJAX. Потом делаешь импорт в Android Studio и компилишь. Так что ли?

Comment: Про XML можно забыть, если посмотреть в сторону JSON. Он я вляется "родным" форматом для Android.